# Update nested string field

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql, elasticsearch-painless

I am trying to update a field `image.uri` by `_update_by_query`:

```
POST user/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.image.uri = 'https://example.com/default/image/profile.jpg'",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
         {
              "exists": {
                "field": "image.id"
              }
          }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But it throws error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "runtime error",
        "script_stack": [
          "ctx._source.image.uri = 'https://example.com/default/image/profile.jpg'",
          "                 ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script": "ctx._source.image.uri = 'https://example.com/default/image/profile.jpg'",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    ],
    "type": "script_exception",
    "reason": "runtime error",
    "script_stack": [
      "ctx._source.image.uri = 'https://example.com/default/image/profile.jpg'",
      "                 ^---- HERE"
    ],
    "script": "ctx._source.image.uri = 'https://example.com/default/image/profile.jpg'",
    "lang": "painless",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "null_pointer_exception",
      "reason": null
    }
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

A sample document:

```
{
    "image": {
        "uri": "https://example.com/resources/uploads/default_files/profile/thumb/large/default_profile.jpg"
    },
    "created": "2018-06-06T21:49:26Z",
    "uid": 1,
    "name": "Jason Cameron",
    "username": "jason"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED RESPONE**

The problem could be coming from a document without `image` object in it.

Try to add `strict` mapping if possible, to avoid indexing documents without `image` object.

**OLD RESPONSE/"\' are correct for use inside painless script as string**

Your problem comes as use of `'` to encapsulate your uri, strings must be encapsulated by `"`.

Try to modify your script as:

```
 "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.image.uri = \"https://example.com/default/image/profile.jpg\"",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
```

Comment: Hm I've tried it, and worked as expected with mapping with `object.id`. Should you share your `image` attributes mapping?

Comment: It updates first level keys like `_source.name`, my query worked for it. But its not updating this nested field. Here is the mapping: `    "image": {
     "properties": {
      "id": {
       "type": "long"
      },
      "uri": {
       "type": "text",
       "fields": {
        "keyword": {
         "type": "keyword",
         "ignore_above": 256
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }`

Comment: What ES version are you using? I've tried your script with ES 6 and your image mapping with `"query":{"match_all":{}}` and it worked correctly.

Comment: This worked for me: https://gist.github.com/jordivador/eaa38fe60bbf83235ec2d0af83ab2112

Comment: I've found your possible error, try to found any document that has no `image` attribute at all.

Comment: I did, no documents found. I am trying to identify the issue. How can I check in `painless` if its null?

Comment: Elvis operator is your friend for null values: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/6.3/painless-operators.html#_null_safe